# Room database not updating values

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, drag-and-drop, android-room

I have a recyclerview with drag and drop enabled.

When I reorder the items I am trying to save the swap postion of the items.

Here is my ontouch listener.

```
override fun onMove(
                recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
                target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            ): Boolean {
                // Notify your adapter that an item is moved from x position to y position
                mOrderChanged = true
                val from = viewHolder.absoluteAdapterPosition
                val to = target.absoluteAdapterPosition
                updatePos.invoke(
                    UpdatePos(
                        fromId = cps[from].id,
                        fromPos = from,
                        toId = cps[to].id,
                        toPos = to
                    )
                )
```

`updatePos` is a listener that listener triggers the following code in the fragment.

```
{ updateData ->

                        vm.swapCpPosition(
                            updateData.fromId, updateData.fromPos, updateData.toId, updateData.toPos
                        )


                }
```

`swapCpPosition` looks like this

```
fun swapCpPosition(fromID : Long,fromPos:Int,toID:Long,toPos:Int){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            dailyChartRepo.swapCpPosition(fromID, fromPos, toID, toPos)
        }
    }
```

`dailyChartRepo.swapCpPosition` in the repo:

```
suspend fun swapCpPosition(fromID : Long,fromPos:Int,toID:Long,toPos:Int){
      dailyChartDao.swapCpPosition(fromID,fromPos,toID,toPos)

  }
```

`dailyChartDao.swapCpPosition` in the dao :

```
 @Query("update cp_view_group set position =:pos where cp_id=:cpID")
    fun setCpPosition(pos: Int, cpID: Long){
        Timber.i("room: pos $pos id $cpID")
    }

    @Transaction
    suspend fun swapCpPosition(fromID: Long, fromPos: Int, toID: Long, toPos: Int) {
        setCpPosition((toPos+1), fromID)
        setCpPosition((fromPos+1), toID)
    }
```

the queries are being executed according to the logs

```
2021-10-25 12:26:58.368 26091-26180/in_.co.iptech.purusharth I/mpurusharth_DailyChartDaoNew$DefaultImpls: room: pos 1 id 1633341941324
2021-10-25 12:26:58.369 26091-26180/in_.co.iptech.purusharth I/mpurusharth_DailyChartDaoNew$DefaultImpls: room: pos 2 id 17
```

in the list id `17` is the first item and id `1633341941324` is the inital item position.

However the postion values are not saved in the databse and the postion for id `17` is still `1` and the `id 1633341941324` is still at number 2
[image]

what am I missing, why are the values not being updated ??

Answer (score 0):

this is insert your model

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun insertData(data: yourModel)
```

get item that want update)

```
@Query("select * from table where id=:id")
suspend fun getData(id: Int): your model?
```

then use transaction and update

```
@Transaction
suspend fun updateData(id: Int, name:String) {
    val data: yourModel? = getData(id)
    if (data!= null) {
        data.title= name
        insertData(data)
    }
}
```